# chrome Webdriver can't be resolved to a type error eclipse and java

Tags: java, eclipse, selenium

Im trying to do some automation projects with chrome, java and selenium and having problems importing the chrome driver.

```
package main;

import org.openqa.selenium.*;

public class SitePoster {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
         //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "./pathtodriver");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        //Getting error saying "ChromeDriver can't be resolved to a type"
    } 

}
```

Comment: need to import chromedriver

Answer (score 10):

**chrome Webdriver can't be resolved to a type error eclipse and java:-**

*I was getting same problem with selenium -java 3.141.59 on macOs.Check below steps to resolve issue:-*

1. Create a new Java Project >class >Create Class name
2. Right click on Project >Property > Build path > Libraries
3. Add external Jars to Classpath download from selenium client & web 
   driver language binding.
4. Apply and Close.

Hope you got your Issue fixed. Kindly reply back in case of any issue.

Comment: Your answer is correct but please also add screenshots if possible to support your answer.

Answer (score 5):

Even after installing the required jar files I was facing the same error message and then I updated the compiler compliance level in the Java compiler to 1.8(depends) and then error disappeared. It solved my issue.

You can follow below steps:

1. Select the Java project(created one)
2. Build Path
3. Configure build path
4. Java compiler
5. Change the compiler compliance level(I selected 1.8)
6. Apply and Close.

Answer (score 2):

The solution for me was the POM specified an older version of ChromeDriverManager which was how chromeDriver was obtained in my build. If you are specifying a location using setProperty this will of course not apply to you. But it helps to check with the version of the dependencies in your POM

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
        <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.6.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

That did it!

Answer (score 2):

Add Selenium Jar Files to ClassPath instead of ModulePath
[image]

Comment: Works in my case. Have Eclipse 2021 and added JAR to module path instead of Classpath. Adding jar to Classpath resolves issue for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

ChromeDriver is one extra level nested in org.openqa.selenium package. Try with import statement

> org.openqa.selenium.chrome.*;

OR

> import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

Answer (score 1):

The error says it all :

```
"ChromeDriver can't be resolved to a type"
```

While working with *Selenium 3.x* you have to mention the *Key-Value* pair through `System.setProperty()` line mandatory as follows :

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/path/to/chromedriver");
```

Additionally, as per best practices instead of `import org.openqa.selenium.*;` you have to mention the individual packages for import as follows :

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
```

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the exact same error. It did resolve for me after performing the below steps.

1. Right click on Project>Buildpath>configure build path
2. Libraries>Add external Jars.
3. Add the external Jars from the 'libs' folder first, then add the 'Client component' ones.

   ```
   import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;    
   import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;        

   public class test1 {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\nsukumar\\Documents\\selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
           WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
           driver.get("https://google.co.in");

       } 
   }
   ```

Answer (score 1):

Try to edit external jars in the `ModulePath` & `Classpath`.

See on the picture link -->
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to attach jar files. I was getting the exactly the same issue.
you need to install "Selenium 3.4.0" jar files.
Which contains lib folder of .jar files and "client-combined-3.4.0-nodeps" files.
After you attach these jar files refresh the code by giving run command.

Answer (score 0):

Adding Selenium jar files from the build path > add external libraries fix the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

For Linux user go to terminal check google version with below command

**google-chrome --version**

**OP**:- *Google Chrome 69.0.3497.100*

Now, Upgrade chrome using below command

**sudo apt --only-upgrade install google-chrome-stable**

After this check the google chrome version using above same command

**google-chrome --version**

**OP**:- *Google Chrome 78.0.3904.87*

Now you need to download the same version google driver. you can find it from the below link.

**https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/index.html?path=78.0.3904.70/**

Download google driver and extract it and save the path and use it in the code, Now run the code.

Answer (score 0):

if you are not able to add this statement

```
 import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
```

the probable reason is you are using **maven** and you have not included the below

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.seleniumhq.selenium/selenium-chrome-driver -->
<dependency>
<groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
<artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
<version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

Even if we put the below statement, problem still comes

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Software\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
```

So the solution is goto maven repository site and take the chrome dependency from there to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

This type of error occurs when you have added the external jars in the ModulePath. To resolve this issue, you can remove the external jars from the node "Modulepath". Select the node "Classpath" then add the external jars. Review that all the jars are under the node "Classpath"

Answer (score 0):

When adding external jars, make sure you add the jars in the lib folder first before adding the ones in the main selenium-java folder. This made the difference for me.

```java
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class testdemo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\Users\\victo\\OneDrive\\Documents\\driverchrome\\ChromeDriver.exe");
        
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();
        
        driver.get(" https:google.com");
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced this error when using Latest Eclipse 2021-03 and Selenium 3

To resolve this, add your Selenium standalone jar file in Classpath instead of Module path. also do not forgot to delete the existing Jar files in modulepath, apply and then apply&close.

Answer (score 0):

Even after installing the required jar files I was facing the same error message and then I updated the compiler compliance level in the Java compiler to 1.8(depends) and then error disappeared. It solved my issue.

You can follow below steps:

- Select the Java project(created one)
- Build Path
  Configure build path
  Java compiler
  Change the compiler compliance level(I selected 1.8)
  Apply and Close.
  This answer helped me as well. I changed my compliance level from 15 to 1.8.

Answer (score 0):

Ran in to this problem today and it turns out I simply forgot to add the .jar files from the 'lib' folder.  Hope this helps someone.