# The type org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver is not accessible with Java 12

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, java-12

I am new to Selenium for the purpose of familiarizing for an internship. Currently, I am having a problem with importing chromedriver jar. I am currently using Java 12. It is weird because the error seems to go away when I switch the compiler to Java 1.8. Can anyone help me with this problem?

```
package co.edureka.selenium.webdriver.sj;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class launchbrowser {

    public static WebDriver driver = null;

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver",".\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");

        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.navigate().to("https://amazon.com");
    }

}
```

"import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver" displays this error

> "The type org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver is not accessible";

"ChromeDriver()" displays this error

> "ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type"

Comment: How do you manage the project dependencies? How are you running the code shared in the question (as modular or non-modular jar)?

Answer (score 1):

These error messages...

```
The type org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver is not accessible
```

and

```
ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type
```

...implies that ChromeDriver wasn't resolved at compiletime.

---

A bit more details about the binaries and your *test framework* i.e. *Selenium jars* or *maven* would have helped us to analyze the issue in a better way. Presumably you have **resolved** the *WebDriver* and *ChromeDriver* from one JAR source (i.e. either *selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59* or *selenium-java-3.141.59* JARs) but **compiletime** the Classes are trying to get resolved from the other JAR. Hence you see the error.

---

### Solution

- Either keep only  **selenium-server-standalone-3.141.59.jar** as an external JAR.
- Or keep only  **selenium-java-3.141.59** JARs as an external JARs.
- Remove all the other *Selenium Java Client JARs*.
- *Clean* your *Project Workspace* through your *IDE* and *Rebuild* your project with required dependencies only.
- Take a *System Reboot*.
- Execute your `@Test`.

Additionally, you need to provide the *absolute* path of the *chromedriver.exe* as follows:

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","C:\\full_path\\Driver\\chromedriver.exe");
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [chrome Webdriver can't be resolved to a type error eclipse and java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897286/chrome-webdriver-cant-be-resolved-to-a-type-error-eclipse-and-java/48898627#48898627)
- [java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problems : WebDriver/ChromeDriver cannot be resolved to a type error while executing selenium tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50111517/java-lang-error-unresolved-compilation-problems-webdriver-chromedriver-cannot/50114884#50114884)

Comment: *`ChromeDriver` cannot be resolved to a type* is not possibly an error from the line of code you've pointed. It looks more like a compile error.

Comment: @Naman You were right. Updated the answer. Let me know your feedback.