# selenium configuration ChromeDriver works but ChromeOptions not found

Tags: java, selenium, google-chrome

I have just configured Selenium for Java on Eclipse on a new PC (have configured without issue for a number of times in the past) and can run a sample code

```
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

 
public class AutoLogin {
 
public static void main(String[] args) {
    
    System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C://pathtodrive//chromedriver.exe");
    
    WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();

    
// Open Register
driver.get("https://google.com");
 
// Maximize browser
 
driver.manage().window().maximize();
 
}
 
}
```

The above code works perfectly and could see google.com open in the browser window. Now I wanted to change some of the default options like default download directory, certificate check etc. I could see the ChromeOptions.class under imported client-combined-3.141.59.jar

But when I write

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
```

the eclipse shows error

*the import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions cannot be resolved*

please advise what could be wrong? and which configuration I am missing

> os:        windows 10 64 bit eclipse:   Helios Service Release 1
> (Build id: 20100917-0705 ) 32 bit java: jre1.8.0_261 32 bit

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48897286/chrome-webdriver-cant-be-resolved-to-a-type-error-eclipse-and-java/48898627

Comment: @MohamedSulaimaanSheriff the issue is a bit different here... the libraries are in the build path and the code I posted works fine means ChromeDriver is working fine. It's only when I try to use ChromeOptions it's showing the error.

Comment: Not exactly sure, why you are getting issue. But couple of suggestions  first try to change JRE to JDK folder. Also any particular reason you are using 32 bit Java / Eclipse ?

Comment: Probably when you copy-pasted that line from some web page you took some invisible symbols there..

Comment: @AlexeyR. just checked for some invisible symbols but couldn't find any. Here the code could not reference to ChromeOptions class but could refer to ChromeDriver class. Do you really think that issue is related to some hidden symbols??

Comment: @rahulrai chromedriver exe is 32 bit so tried to be consistent with jdk and eclipse.

Comment: I just cannot imagine any other reason that one class is visible and another from the same package is not. Probably it is the bug in eclipse.. Have you tried to clean and then compile the code in command line?

Comment: @Prem - Chrimedriver have only 32 bit version but it support both 32/64 bit device. You can use 64 bit java and eclipse and re-try. It’s difficult to replicate your issue so could not point exact reason for error.

Comment: @rahulrai I just used the 64 bit version of java and eclipse, it's working fine. Thanks.

Comment: Cheers mate. Happy to help.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to the specified import, the driver must be properly initialized. In the code below, it works. That is, first we specify the options, then we use this variable to create a web driver instance.

```
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
options.addArguments("incognito", "headless", "disable-gpu", "window-size=1366,768", "ignore-certificate-errors");
newWebDriver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

And of course the corresponding import.

```
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeOptions;
```