# ChromeOptions not working for me in selenium

Tags: selenium

new to selenium. For some reason ChromeOptions are not working. What am I doing wrong here?
I've tried a few different things I've found here on stackoverflow but nothing is working. It doesn't load the proper profile. Thanks in advance.

```
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

if __name__ == '__main__':
    email = "#"
    password = "#"

    options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument(r'--users-data-dir=C:\Users\dsfgdfs\AppData\Local\Google\Chrome\User Data\Profile 65')

    browser = uc.Chrome(options=options,
    )
    browser.get('https://accounts.google.com/signin/v2/identifier?continue=https%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F&service=mail&sacu=1&rip=1&hl=en&flowName=GlifWebSignIn&flowEntry=ServiceLogin')

    browser.find_element(By.ID, 'identifierId').send_keys(email)

    browser.find_element(
        By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#identifierNext > div > button > span').click()

    password_selector = "#password > div.aCsJod.oJeWuf > div > div.Xb9hP > input"

    WebDriverWait(browser, 10).until(
        EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, password_selector)))

    browser.find_element(

        By.CSS_SELECTOR, password_selector).send_keys(password)

    browser.find_element(
        By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#passwordNext > div > button > span').click()
```

Answer (score 0):

*You have missing import*

```
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
```

Comment: Hello, I've added this to my import but still the options are not being imported.

Comment: checkout this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63681266/selenium-configuration-chromedriver-works-but-chromeoptions-not-found]